# BigDecimal Round UP OR DOWN

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Tengo estos dos escenarios trabajando con bigdecimal:

```
BigDecimal result;

escenario 1: result = 19315859.60145000000000 ---[should be]--> 19315859.6014

escenario 2: result = 66841687.43665000000000 ---[should be]--> 66841687.4367
```

El problema es que estoy usando una variable (result) y si se aplica a esta variable `.setScale (4, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)` funcionará con escenario 2, pero no con el escenario 1, lo mismo si utilizo `.setScale 4, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN)` escenario 1 funcionará pero escenario 2 no.

Lo que quiero hacer es que si el valor anterior es mayor que 5 aumentar en 1 y sino dejarlo como está.

```
Ex: 
19315859.60145000000000 : ok the previous value is 4 so y leave it and the result should be 19315859.6014.

66841687.43665000000000 : ok the previous value is 6 so y increase 1 and the result should be  66841687.4367
```

Comment: Bien raro lo que pides. Ninguno de los rounding mode de `BigDecimal` hace eso.  Solo para entender, cual sería el resultado deseado para los números siguientes: `19315859.60146000000000`, `19315859.60144000000000`, `66841687.43666000000000`, `66841687.43664000000000`. (De paso, parece que alguien te tradujo la pregunta a medias, sería bueno que la terminaras de traducir).

Answer (score 1):

Buenas,

Yo en tu lugar no usaria el redondeo que viene por defecto en BigDecimal, usaria el RoundingMode del módulo java.lang del API que puedes consultar aqui:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html

En tu caso, para usar ese redondeo usa la constante HALF-UP de esta.

Hace poco implementé una calculadora virtual de este modo y funcionó muy bien.

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir algo de código a tu respuesta?